# Right aligned cursor not showing through in a JTextPane component

Tags: java, swing, cursor, textfield

I have a JTextPane sandwiched between 2 JLabels - is there a known reason why the cursor shows through if i have it on the left most part of the textpane but not on the right?

Here is the code to better demonstrate what i mean:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;

public class Testing {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel cp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        f.setContentPane(cp);

        final SubPanel subPanel = new SubPanel();

        cp.add(subPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("Align"));
        final JComboBox alignCB = new JComboBox(new String[] {"left", "centre", "right"});
        alignCB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                subPanel.align((String) alignCB.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(alignCB);
        buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("Justify"));
        final JComboBox justifyCB = new JComboBox(new String[] {"left", "centre", "right"});
        justifyCB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                subPanel.justify((String) justifyCB.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(justifyCB);

        JTextField tf = new JTextField("TF");
        tf.setBorder(null);
        buttonPanel.add(tf);

        cp.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        f.pack();
        f.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        f.setLocation(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static class SubPanel extends JPanel {
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        TextPaneWidget[] tps = new TextPaneWidget[3];

        public SubPanel() {
            //                setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
            setBorder(null);
            //                innerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
            innerPanel.setBorder(null);

            for (int i = 0; i < tps.length; i++) {
                tps[i] = new TextPaneWidget();
            }

            int gridy = 0;
            for (TextPaneWidget tp : tps) {
                innerPanel.add(tp, new GridBagConstraints(0,gridy, 1,1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));
                gridy++;
            }

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            add(innerPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0,0, 1,1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));
        }

        public void align(String alignment) {
            System.out.println("Align: " + alignment);

            int anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            if ("right".equals(alignment)) {
                anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            } else if ("left".equals(alignment)) {
                anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            }

            GridBagLayout gbl = (GridBagLayout) getLayout();
            gbl.setConstraints(innerPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0,0, 1,1, 1.0, 0.0, anchor, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        public void justify(String justification) {
            System.out.println("Justify: " + justification);

            for (TextPaneWidget tp : tps) {
                tp.justify(justification);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MyDocument extends DefaultStyledDocument {
        @Override
        public void insertString(int offset, String text, AttributeSet attributeSet) throws BadLocationException {
            SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet(attributeSet);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, Color.WHITE);
            StyleConstants.setBackground(attrs, Color.RED);
            super.insertString(offset, text, attrs);
        }
    }

    public static class TextPaneWidget extends JPanel {
        JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
        JLabel lSpace = new JLabel("   ");
        JLabel rSpace = new JLabel("   ");

        public TextPaneWidget() {
            //                setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
            setBorder(null);

            Font font = new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 13);
            tp.setBorder(null);
            tp.setDocument(new MyDocument());
            tp.setFont(font);
            tp.setText("Text");
            tp.setOpaque(true);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            lSpace.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
            lSpace.setOpaque(true);
            lSpace.setBorder(null);
            add(lSpace, new GridBagConstraints(0,0, 1,1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));

            add(tp, new GridBagConstraints(1,0, 1,1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));

            rSpace.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
            rSpace.setOpaque(true);
            rSpace.setBorder(null);
            add(rSpace, new GridBagConstraints(2,0, 1,1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    tp.setCaretPosition((e.getX() < tp.getX()) ? 0 : tp.getText().length());
                    tp.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });

            lSpace.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    tp.setCaretPosition(0);
                    tp.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });

            rSpace.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    tp.setCaretPosition(tp.getText().length());
                    tp.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });

        }

        public void justify(String justification) {
            double leftWeight = 0.5;
            double rightWeight = 0.5;
            if ("right".equals(justification)) {
                leftWeight = 1.0;
                rightWeight = 0.0;
            } else if ("left".equals(justification)) {
                leftWeight = 0.0;
                rightWeight = 1.0;
            }

            GridBagLayout gbl = (GridBagLayout) getLayout();
            gbl.setConstraints(lSpace, new GridBagConstraints(0,0, 1,1, leftWeight, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));
            gbl.setConstraints(rSpace, new GridBagConstraints(2,0, 1,1, rightWeight, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL, new Insets(0,0,0,0), 0, 0));
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing it on a Windows XP computer with Java 6.  The cursor shows up fine on the JTextPane no matter what the alignment or justification.  Now, I do have to left click on the JTextPane where I want the cursor to be to give the JTextPane focus.  You can't put the cursor past the rightmost character when using a left to right character orientation.

Comment: if i remove the setBorder(null) on the textfield it works fine but puts a horrible white border around it. I've tried changing it to    tp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,1)); but again, i get a slight white gap - is there a way of setting the empty border gap colour??

Comment: I don't understand what effect you want.  tp.setBorder(null) is the same as tp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));

Comment: im using windows 7 so not sure if its different but basically the cursor disappears from the right side of the text box (doesnt happen on the left). If i use tp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,1)); (note the 1 for the right border) it adds a small white border and the cursor appears if i click to the right most point of the text box - my question is why does this work when creating an empty border but not for any of the other border types...??

Comment: Ah, I finally understand what you're asking.  I'm guessing that there's no place in a JTextPane to draw the rightmost cursor unless you provide a one pixel space on the right.  If you want a one pixel right line border, you're going to have to write your own class that implements Border.  None of the standard BorderFactory methods will do this.

Comment: You could use tp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,1,0,1)); for a consistent look.  :-)  Otherwise, you can extend AbstractBorder to get the effect you want.

Comment: The empty border doesn't paint anything.  All of the other borders paint, which I'm guessing paints over the text pane cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what's happening.  Thanks for providing the code.

When you define a JTextPane, the default border is a 3 pixel empty border.  This empty border provides a place for the text pane cursor to show when the cursor is at the rightmost position.  The cursor is at the rightmost position to allow characters to be typed at the end of a line of characters.

When you define a null border, which is the same as a 0 pixel empty border, there's no place for the text pane cursor to be drawn when it's in the rightmost position.

In order to see the cursor in the rightmost position, you have to define an empty border with at least 1 right pixel.  If you want it to be more visually appealing, include 1 left pixel.

```
tp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,1,0,1));
```

You have to define an empty border, because an empty border is the only `Border` that does not paint.  A `Border` that paints will paint over the text pane cursor in the rightmost position.

So, you are required to use an empty border with at least one right pixel for a JTextPane to display the rightmost cursor.

Edited to add:

When you're using the `GridBagLayout`, a method like this one reduces the number of parameters that you have to deal with when you add a component.

```
protected void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
        int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, 
        Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
            gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
    container.add(component, gbc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the background to the following fixes this...

```
tp.setBackground(Color.RED);
tp.setOpaque(true);
```