# Change EmptyBorder space colour

Tags: java, swing, colors, border

Does anyone know whether its possible to change the colour of the empty space provided by the `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()` method. By default it always sets it to white - i want to set it to whatever colour the background of my JFrame is (i.e. grey).

Answer (score 3):

You want an empty border that has a color?  The point of an empty border is that it takes up no space.  Something with no space can't  have a color.  Did you want a line border instead?

see [BorderFactory#createLineBorder(Color color)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createLineBorder%28java.awt.Color%29)

Comment: Empty border can have insets greater than 0. The purpose of empty border is to not paint anything!

Comment: The reason i ask this is that for some reason my cursor disappears from the right side of the text pane if I have anything over than an emptyBorder. Please see my previous question here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340851/right-aligned-cursor-not-showing-through-in-a-jtextpane-component#comment19935043_14340851

Comment: I suppose my question should be why does the cursor show up when i have an empty border but not when i use any of the other border types?

Comment: @maloney: See the answer to your previous question.

Comment: -1 - as @GuillaumePolet already noted, the answer is ... wrong ;-) Wondering: how could anybody (or three bodies) have upvoted this?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the empty border & color (or 'not' for plain) to a panel added to the content pane.

[image: Blue Colored EmptyBorder]  [image: Plain Colored EmptyBorder]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PlainColoredEmptyBorder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 30, 20, 30));

                JTree tree = new JTree();
                tree.setVisibleRowCount(4);
                gui.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
                gui.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
                f.add(gui);
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this method on a JTextField still produces a white space around the box. Is there any way of doing this and still having the cursor show up when clicked to the right most point?

Comment: I have, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340851/right-aligned-cursor-not-showing-through-in-a-jtextpane-component#comment19935043_14340851

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the cursor show up when i have an empty border but not when i use any of the other border types?

Because an empty border is the only `Border` that does not paint.  Any other type of Border will paint over the text pane cursor.

Putting your text pane inside of a `JPanel` with a background color doesn't work either because your text pane will be painted after the parent `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background colour of the text field and setting it to opaque fixes this